# Mongoose updateMany for array of array

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, many-to-many, backend

Currently, I am working on a project on academic management of the university, every semester students will get marks for training and if someone is below 50/100 they will receive a warning email. I use mongoose, namely mongo atlas to store data, expressjs for backend, I create a model called "classes" to define the information of classes as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const classSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  consultant: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Consultant',
    required: true
  },
  classname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  studentList: [
    {
      code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

const Class = mongoose.model('Class', classSchema)

module.exports = Class
```

and this my model of student:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  fullname: {
    type: String
  },
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  classname: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Male', 'Female', 'No Record'],
    default: 'No Record'
  },
  birthday: {
    type: String
  },
  vnumail: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
  },
  vnumail: {
    type: String,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
  },
  profileImage: {
    type: String,
    default:
      'https://kittyinpink.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/facebook-default-photo-male_1-1.jpg'
  },
  hometown: {
    type: String
  },
  accademicTrainningList: [
    {
      score: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      schoolYear: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      semester: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['1', '2'],
        default: '1'
      },
      classification: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: [
          'Excellent',
          'Good',
          'Intermediate',
          'Average',
          'Weak',
          'Fail',
          'No Record'
        ],
        default: 'No Record'
      }
    }
  ],
  scoreList: [
    {
      score: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
      subjectCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      subjectName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  receiveScholarship: [
    {
      scholarshipName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      value: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  prizeList: [
    {
      constestName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      ranking: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  scienceContestPrizeList: [
    {
      constestName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      ranking: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  wentAbroad: [
    {
      country: {
        type: String
      },
      time: {
        type: Date
      }
    }
  ],
  tookTheTest: [
    {
      testName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      ranking: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  punishList: [
    {
      studentCode: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    }
  ]
})

studentSchema.pre('save', function (error, doc, next) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    next(new Error('There was a duplicate key error'))
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

const Student = mongoose.model('Students', studentSchema)

module.exports = Student
```

I then create a route to add a new class and The input is a .xlsx file and I will extract the information in that file and add the properties of the xlsx file and add it to the database. I use the xlsx - npm library to extract the information and save it. this image demonstrate my input file[image: input file]

```
router.post(
  '/',
  upload.single('excel'),
  extract_data,
  add_new_class,
  add_students_from_excel,
  add_parent_from_excel,
  add_user_from_excel
)
```

This is the middleware I use to extract the information:

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx')
const { formatClassname } = require('../../helpers')

exports.extract_data = (req, res, next) => {
  let { file } = req
  let workbook = xlsx.readFile(file.path)
  const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames
  let { classname, schoolYear, semester } = req.body

  data = []

  sheet_name_list.forEach(sheet => {
    let workSheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet]

    let dataArr = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet)
    dataArr.forEach(info => {
      var fullname = info['Họ tên ']
      var code = info['Mã SV ']
      var birthday = info['Ngày sinh ']
      var score = info['Điểm ']

      data.push({
        fullname,
        code,
        birthday,
        classname: formatClassname(classname),
        accademicTrainningList: {
          score,
          schoolYear,
          semester,
          classification:
            (score >= 90 && 'Excellent') ||
            (score >= 80 && score < 90 && 'Good') ||
            (score >= 70 && score < 80 && 'Intermediate') ||
            (score >= 60 && score < 70 && 'Average') ||
            (score >= 50 && score < 60 && 'Weak') ||
            (score < 50 && 'Fail')
        }
      })
    })
  })

  req.data = data
  next()
}
```

then in the next route, i insertMany into collection "students":

```
exports.add_students_from_excel = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { data } = req

  var studentList = []

  data.forEach((student, index) => {
    var {
      fullname,
      code,
      birthday,
      classname,
      accademicTrainningList
    } = student

    studentList.push({
      fullname,
      birthday,
      classname,
      code,
      vnumail: code + '@vnu.edu.vn',
      classname,
      accademicTrainningList
    })
  })

  Student.insertMany(studentList, { ordered: false })
    .then(docs => {
      console.log('new students were inserted, reload the database')
      next()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (
        (err.name === 'BulkWriteError' || err.name === 'MongoError') &&
        err.code === 11000
      ) {
        console.log('new students were inserted, reload the database')
        next()
      } else {
        res.status(500).json({ err })
      }
    })
}
```

I succeeded and I added data about new class in model "class" and student list in model "student". This is the input data image and the result is saved on the mongo atlas
[image: class mongo atlas]
[image: student mongo atlas]

But as you can see, the "academicTrainningList" attribute in the "student" model is an array and I just added the first one, now I want to add more items for the second semester of 2016 and the next, i will have to updateMany, the input will be an xlsx file with the same student list and the score will be different, but i don't know what the syntax will look like, i'm a complete newbie and self-taught, thank you for your time time to read through this post and take the time to help me, it is very meaningful to me, have a nice day

Comment: So basically you want to update the documents array by pushing new elements to it, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, each of academicTrainingList will push new item respectively according to its code

Comment: check the answer I´ve given below, see If that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update many resources you could .find(query) the resources and then for each resource:

`forEach((doc)=>{doc.academicTrainingList.push(NEW_ITEM)}`

I don´t know the logic behind your .xlsx files, but you could search your item Id in the table to find the correct NEW_ITEM to push to the array

Comment: sorry but i think it not work out in this way, i tried

Comment: Thank you Luis, base on your idea, i am now can handle my problem, it means a lot to me, it is my theis project, thank you so much, hope you have a good day

Comment: You could provide me with the details in case my answer is helpfuo for someone in the future

Comment: ok, you know that academicTrainingList is an array, so you use loop forEach, it correct, but the value to push into each item is different so that is the problem, here is my code

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ninja-firestore-tut-4fc86.appspot.com/o/like.jpg?alt=media&token=b788f85f-b481-47f5-81df-d7481424b1e6

Comment: size: length of array, when the counter 's value increases equal to the size so end the loop and response the message 'updated' to user